# Android - cannot call different phone number from list view but showing different phone number

Tags: java, android

Below is the view method in list view adapter extending base adapter

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi = convertView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_people_list_item, null);
        callPeopleContact = (ImageButton) vi.findViewById(R.id.people_contact_call_icon);
        try {
            jsonTotalObject = this_dataJsonArray.getJSONObject(position);
            jsonUserObject = jsonTotalObject.getJSONObject("User");
            telephone = jsonUserObject.getString("office_phone");
            intentToCall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + telephone));
            callPeopleContact.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this_context, android.Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                            // TODO: Consider calling
                            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                            //                                          int[] grantResults)
                            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                            return;
                        }
                        this_context.startActivity(intentToCall);
}
            });

            });
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return vi;
    }
    return vi;
}
```

Though the phone number is appearing all different in the list view,when i click the call icon the number is same for all list item.Why is that?
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Quick fix**

Instead of creating `intentToCall` a class level variable, define it locally with `final` modifier and it will do the job.

change

```
intentToCall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + telephone));
```

to

```
final Intent intentToCall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + telephone));
```

**Detail explanation:**

When you create `intent` instance variable, variable will remain same everytime and keep on getting reinitialized with new values as you scroll down/up and will precisely hold value for the item scrolled

Answer (score 0):

ListView has this drawback that when you use onClickListener inside getView it gives you wrong item position. Either you use RecyclerView or Following code

```
    class DetailAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        Context ctx;
        int countt = 1;
        int j;
        private int mSelectedPosition = -1;
        DetailAdapter(Context c) {
            ctx = c;
            layinfa = LayoutInflater.from(ctx);
        }

        public int getSelectedPosition() { return mSelectedPosition; }
        // getter and setter methods for the field above
        public void setSelectedPosition(int selectedPosition) {
            mSelectedPosition = selectedPosition;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            Log.i("*******", new StringBuilder().append(list_vehidetai.size()).toString());
            return list_vehidetai.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int i) {
            return list_vehidetai.get(i);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int i) {
            return i;
        }

       public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi = convertView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_people_list_item, null);
        callPeopleContact = (ImageButton) vi.findViewById(R.id.people_contact_call_icon);
        try {
            jsonTotalObject = this_dataJsonArray.getJSONObject(position);
            jsonUserObject = jsonTotalObject.getJSONObject("User");
            telephone = jsonUserObject.getString("office_phone");
            intentToCall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + telephone));
            callPeopleContact.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
 if (mSelectedPosition == position) {


                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this_context, android.Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                            // TODO: Consider calling
                            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                            //                                          int[] grantResults)
                            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                            return;
                        }
                        this_context.startActivity(intentToCall);
}
}
            });

            });
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return vi;
    }
}
```

getter setter of getting selected itemposition

Third option is setItemClickListener on listView